# Cost of launch unrelated to cost of building rocket

Tags: launch, rockets

ULA CEO Tory Bruno said long time ago that only 1/2 cost of orbital launch is cost of building of rocket. SpaceX never denied this. F9R block 5 total cost of launch can be about 60-80 million per flight. Atlas V cost per flight can be about 110 million.

Half of this is cost of building rocket.

Second half is unrelated to building of rocket (or refurbishment of F9R used 1st stage ).

**So let speak only about the second half.**

What are exactly things that cost SpaceX F9R 30-40 million per flight, ULA Atlas V 55 million per flight.

What I read cost of fuel is only 3% cost of flight ( so 6% of second half ).

After each launch, you need refurbish launch head, decoupler and umbilicals and then before flight, there is flight door installation. That together can take about 4-5 days, but doesn't sound so expansive.

Than there are things like stage integration, payload integration, transportation costs, storage tanks for fuel, oxidizer which must be refilled, some fueling hardware ( or cost of fueling ), those big white cylinders, that protect launch pad from lighting ( forget name ) and so on.

F9R engines must be, before each flight test fired at McGregor test site, but ULA does not have similar test site.

F9R also fly on subcooled LOX and cooled propellant, so they need some special subcooling hardware.

Tory Bruno also said that Vulcan will need some massive water sound suppression system, because when sound blast hit ground and bounce back it could damage spacecraft, rocket.

Than there are things like annual insurance fees or annual cost of renting of launch site from government, which can be calculate over one launch.

So can anybody here give exact breakdown of those costs for either F9R or Atlas 5 or any other orbital rocket.

For example Atlas 5 :

1. Cost of fuel and oxidizer - 6 % of the second half (unrelated to cost of building rocket).
2. Refurbishment of the launch tower after each flight - 10 % of the second half.
3. transportation costs - 5 % of the second half.
4. payload integration - 10 %.

and so on.

I don't know any of this figures for sure, but want have better idea, how big each of this costs items could be and which are the most expensive.

If there is some cost item, that I didn't mention, you can of course mentioned it by yourself.

Comment: You've done a pretty good gob outlining all the other costs factors.  Getting actual numbers will be a guessing game, as those figures are highly proprietary for most if not all vendors.

Comment: You're making a big assumption that the ratio of costs is the same for SpaceX, just because they haven't said anything in response to what ULA has said. SpaceX has been aggressively pursuing cost reduction since the start, and reduction of operational costs is a good part of why they were cheaper well before they ever started landing rockets.

Comment: Insurance may be significant. If you want to insure the cost of the launch, and 1 launch in n fails, then the cost of insurance is going to be more than 1/n of whatever a failure costs (if it was less than 1/n then the insurance company would lose money).

Comment: Are you including personell costs?

Comment: ULA could also be including fixed costs per year amortized over the number of launches.   SpaceX has about 7,000 employees.  Only a subset of them are involved in actual rocket construction.  The rest would be facilities managers, support staff, sales people, maintenance workers, flight controllers, accountants, secretaries, etc.  People you have to pay no matter how many rockets you fly.  Then there are building maintenance costs,  leasing / refurb costs for launch facilities,  and on and on.  the more you fly, the lower the per-flight fraction of the fixed costs to recover.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff SpaceX lower both cost of building F9 and it operational costs so overall ratio could be the same. F9R block 5 also fly on subcooled LOX and cooled RP1 and this subcooling should result in higher operational costs.

Comment: @Dragongeek Of course

Comment: I try transfer this thread to Nasa spaceflight forum - General discussion section, maybe someone can give better answer.

Comment: Again, your assumption that it was the same in the first place is invalid. SpaceX is not ULA, the two have completely different cost structures.

Comment: https://spacenews.com/spacex-targeting-24-hour-turnaround-in-2019-full-reusability-still-in-the-works/: "Musk estimated 60 percent of the Falcon 9’s marginal cost comes from the first stage, 20 percent from the second stage, 10 percent for the fairing, and 10 percent for the everything else associated with the launch. Propellant costs a negligible $300,000 to $400,000, he said."

Comment: Also note that Bruno is not an unbiased source, he is trying to defend ULA's lack of reuse and downplay the significance of SpaceX's reuse of boosters, and has selected his numbers (and sometimes engaged in seriously squirrelly reasoning) to support this. He has launches to sell. SpaceX, on the other hand, has thousands of Starlink satellites to launch, and no parent companies dictating an official position they have to pretend to support.

Comment: It is not just about Tory Bruno opinions, but also Arianespace and Blue origin opinions. S.Israel - CEO of AS and J.Y.Gall president of CNES have very similar opinions on reusability and F9R like Tory Bruno and George Sowers. S.Israel also promised repeatedly that expendable Ariane 6 will match cost per kilogram of F9R ( even without any form of reusability ). Blue origin have contract to deliver Vulcan BE 4 engines. ULA contribute to BE-4 development and BO even design BE-4 engines based on ULA requirements. From BE-4 video that T.Bruno posted on twitter certificate BE-4 for ULA launch has

Comment: even priority over flying them on New Glenn. Obviously Blue Origin is not sure that New Glenn will be commercially as successful as Vulcan and want have some backup option for engines purchaser. Blue Origin have lot of $ so they did not need ULA money, it is more about having some backup option if Vulcan turns up to be much cheaper option than New Glenn. BO have lot of great experience engineers. T.Bruno can not mislead them. SpaceX fired already more than 1000 employees, 100s of them went work for BO. So BO should know everything about F9R booster flyback and decide if there is good

Comment: business case. In other worlds if the Blue Origin was sure that it doesn't need Vulcan as backup option for engines purchaser, it will not design BE-4 for ULA, based on their requirements.

Comment: If SpaceX F9R cost of launch unrelated to cost of rocket was just 10 %, Tory Bruno have more than enough time to decrease ULA Atlas V  ( cost of launch unreal. to cost of build. rocket ) to SX F9R level. T.Bruno said that he cut cost of Atlas 5 to halve, but ratio between cost of building rocket and cost unrelated to build. rocket is the same ( same for Vulcan ). So I don't believe that for F9R it is different. Quite opposite, with subcooling of LOX and cooling of RP1 it should be even more than 50 %.